# scrollTo javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor

I have a js function to scroll into a div.
Here is the function, It works fine, but i'm going to explain later what's wrong with this.

```
        scrollAnchor= function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('generalAnchor');
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = position.left;
        var y = position.top;
        window.scrollTo(x,y);
    }
```

Then an html (nevermind we just need the div generalAnchor)

```
<button onclick="scrollAnchor()">Click me</button>
<div id="generalAnchor">Test</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

This is en example of very long page, so the scroll works fine.
But here is the thing, if i remove all those br then, the scroll isn't working, because the page isn't long enough.

**i could use a true url sometink like myPage#generalAnchor, but in fact i can't do that because i can't load a new page or i loose other informations.**

Do you have an idea do deal with this ?

PS: I put the sample here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHHEHPNB4O1V

There is two case, the first button is working fine. But the second isn't working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to focus on the element you can add an anchor to it. Then focus on him via  `location.href = "#generalAnchor";`

Comment: Or just use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: As i said i can't just do this location.href = "#generalAnchor";
I know this is working fine but the api is much moe complicated than what i show you, so i can't load again the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already thought about to use the default functionality of html anchor?

So if you replace the second button with

```
<a href="#generalAnchor">Click me</a>
```

your code should work.

You can change the design if you want or wrap your button with the link.

Comment: Sorry i can't do that (i mean i can't use link so i can't just use anchor like that). Otherwise i loose information that are needed to load the all page.

The true code is somthing done with ul li and i have no link.

So i know this solution is working fine, but i can't use it in this case.